# Announcement for foreign people in a library (non English-speaking country)

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech

This announcement is made before closure time in a library (latin country):

"XYZ is closing in fifteen minutes. Those users who have to register loans or return in items are kindly requested to go to the service desk."

I would like to know if the text above is a correct and pleasant sentence in English ("loans" means users taking books or DVD's home for periods of time up to about a month), for that kind of announcement in a library.

Comment: I'm guessing you misheard "return in items".  It would have been either "return items" of "turn in items".

Comment: 1) say "patrons", not "users". 2? Say "borrow" instead of "register loans".  Why mention returns? Doesn't the library have a place to put returns (that requires no help from the staff? If you insist, "return items" or "check in material" is fine.

Comment: As a retired librarian, I find it perfectly acceptable (except that it should be 'return items'). To ne a little less formal, you could say something like "If you need to register loans or return items, please go to the service desk now".

Answer (score 0):

Typically "loans" are used to describe the lending of money. You can say "loaned items" to be more specific or consider using "checked-out items."

A few other points: "Users" can be omitted since when you say "Those" it is implied, and "return in items" can be shortened to either "return items" or "turn in items".

A correct version would look like this:
"XYZ is closing in fifteen minutes. Those who have to register checked-out items or return items are kindly requested to go to the service desk."

Comment: So, does "loans" sound bad to a native english speaker? Isn't it like loans for paying a house indeed?

Comment: Although I do often hear this use of "request," it always sounds wrong to me. Among educated  speakers, I think, we ask someone for something but request something from someone. The announcement sounds like an attempt at fancy English, confusing the syntax of the more natural word "ask" with that of the less natural word "request."

Comment: _Loans_ is perfectly fine for library materials (in the UK, at least). The technical term is to _issue_ an item.

Comment: @KateBunting *Issue* would confuse me. It's correct from the POV of the librarian, but the announcement is to the other side of the transaction and they are doing the opposite of issuing, surely?